# libusb for USB target user space driver

Tags: linux, usb, libusb

I would like to implement a USB device driver in user space by means of libusb. I'm using a Linux machine supporting a USB OTG controller which is switched to device mode. The USB host is another machine which needs to communicate with my Linux machine by means of a USB vendor specific interface with a bulk in/out interface.

I would like to know if it is possible to use libusb to communicate with the USB host on the other side. Or, if libusb could be used only for host side functionalities.

If libusb can't be used is there any other way to implement the device driver in user space?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of my knowledge this is not possible. (Vanilla) libusb is only for host usage because the whole process of how to use libusb can only provide this mode.

You can find an answer in the FAQ of the old libusb (before libusbx, the abandoning of the old libusb and the rename of libusbx to the new libusb): 
[libusb FAQ](http://www.libusb.org/wiki/FAQ)

Also there is a question on SO to this topic with some suggestions:
[How to communicate with the USB Host from a Linux USB Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076207/how-to-communicate-with-the-usb-host-from-a-linux-usb-client)

Comment: Hi, wouldn't it be possible to use GadgetFS?

Comment: I haven't heard of this until your comment. The thing is it seems to be possible but I could not find any descriptive documentation to confirm this. So I can not give you any example code or so. Even the guys on the libusb maillist seem not to know too much about it. The github repository seems to be abandoned but don't know about forks. Also there seems to be an issue with composite usb devices.